# How to access vbe video memory?

Tags: memory, video, graphics, operating-system, vbe

I am wondering how to create a pointer to the vbe video memory so I can display graphics from my 32-bit os kernel.  Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the VBE 3.0 standard ([Wikipedia has all the links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_BIOS_Extensions)). Using it, write code to call function 2 to set a graphics mode, making sure you bitwise-OR the mode number with 4000h to tell the BIOS to use a flat linear frame buffer instead of windowed/segmented. Use function 1 to obtain the address of the video buffer (it should be in `ModeInfoBlock.PhysBasePtr`).

There should be plenty of reference code online for things like this.

I suggest to call VBE functions prior to going into protected mode as it will be harder to do afterwards.